# How to add non-modular JARs with split packages to a modular JavaFX project in Intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-module, mapsforge, java-package

My project uses Mapsforge library for displaying maps, and JavaFX for GUI. 
There is a way to compile JavaFX with `javafx-maven-plugin` and stay in the unmodular paradigm, but it seems against the best practices.
The problem is that [mapsforge has split packages](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/issues/1135):
`org.mapsforge.map.rendertheme` is accessible from both `mapsforge.map`, `mapsforge.themes` modules which makes it impossible to require both of them in module-info:

```
java: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Modules mapsforge.map and mapsforge.themes export package org.mapsforge.map.rendertheme to module org.postgresql.jdbc
```

After reading answers to similar questions, I realized that you can add libraries as JARs to the classpath but not as module dependencies. The question is - how you do it correctly in Intellij?

I put three mapsforge jars to ROOT/lib folder, and added all of them as project libraries.
I also tried `Modules -> Dependencies -> Add Jars or Libraries`.

The problem is that I still can't reference classes in those jars:

`java: package org.mapsforge.core.graphics is not visible (package org.mapsforge.core.graphics is declared in the unnamed module, but module rfinder does not read it)`

How can I make the unnamed module with external jars visible to `rfinder`?

PS:
I use maven, and maven-oriented solution would be the best, but I don't know the way to add maven packages to classpath